# What is the Context passed into onReceive() of a BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-context

What is the context that is passed int the `onReceive` method of a `BroadcastReciver`:

```
public void onReceive (Context context, Intent intent)
```

According to the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#onReceive(android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent)):

> The Context in which the receiver is running.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A little research gives below result...

***For static receiver***

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.e("PANKAJ", "Context class " + context.getClass().getName());
        Log.e("PANKAJ", "Application Context class "
                + context.getApplicationContext().getClass().getName());
    }
}
```

I got below log

```
08-05 06:51:33.448: E/PANKAJ(2510): Context class android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext
08-05 06:51:33.448: E/PANKAJ(2510): Application Context class android.app.Application
```

***For bynamic receiver (registered into an Activity MainActivity) like***

```
private BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(android.content.Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.e("PANKAJ", "Context class " + context.getClass().getName());
        Log.e("PANKAJ", "Activity Context class "
            + MainActivity.this.getClass().getName());
        Log.e("PANKAJ", "Application Context class "
            + context.getApplicationContext().getClass().getName());
    }
};
```

I got below log

```
08-05 06:53:33.048: E/PANKAJ(2642): Context class com.example.testapp.MainActivity
08-05 06:53:33.048: E/PANKAJ(2642): Activity Context class com.example.testapp.MainActivity
08-05 06:53:33.048: E/PANKAJ(2642): Application Context class android.app.Application
```

So when it make true the statement given into documentation that *[The Context in which the receiver is running](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#onReceive(android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent))*.

Answer (score 1):

It is an application context . Same one that you get with method

```
getApplicationContext()
```

But:

This instance is a ReceiverRestrictedContext with two main functions disabled; calling registerReceiver() and bindService().  These two functions are not allowed from within an existing BroadcastReceiver.onReceive().  Each time a receiver processes a broadcast, the Context handed to it is a new instance.

Answer (score 0):

Use `getApplicationContext()` to send context to onReceive Method.