# What is context when a BroadcastReceiver is called?

Tags: android, android-context, android-broadcastreceiver

I know this is a broad question, but this might be any average android developer's question. In a `BroadcastReceiver`, what is the `context` parameter passed through `onReceive()` method?

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    }
}
```

I just know we have 3 main types of `context`: `Activity`, `Service`, `Application`.

Comment: [What is the Context passed into onReceive() of a BroadcastReceiver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25132399/what-is-the-context-passed-into-onreceive-of-a-broadcastreceiver)

Comment: Thank you! Does it mean that my app's application class is called when a broadcast is received? @Kunu

Comment: If yours is a static BroadcastReceiver then in your case  Context class is android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext
and  Application Context class is android.app.Application(or your inherited application class if you are using user-defined application)

Comment: "I just know we have 3 main types of context: Activity, Service, Application" -- there are many others. Do not make *any* assumptions about the nature of the `Context` passed into `onReceive()`.

Comment: Yes sir! Copied! I hope I could understand that complicated nature once and for all! @CommonsWare

Answer (score -1):

Initially Context represents environment data and it is used to create application specific resource.

for example, if you create a new object for a class with "this" keyword as its context, that object was resource for that specific class and not for others.

context was also used to share system resources like layoutInflater, NotificationManager and so on.

In Broadcast receiver, context refers to the activity or class in which the broadcast receiver is running. if your "MainActivity" sends a broadcast then the context would have something like the following "com.example.MainActivity"